# C# MVC sending email trouble

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, web

I am new to ASP.NET MVC. I am trying to send an email so I came up with the below code after going through literature on the topic. When I send the email the outcome is a failure to send. Please assist.

The controller has the following code:

```
public JsonResult SendMailToClients()
{
        bool result = false;

        result = SendEmail("tmasaiti@gmail.com", "attachment test ", "<p>Hi Flow<br />Whats poppin, the email you have been waiting for is finally here.<br />Regards<br />The Master</p>");

        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

public bool SendEmail(string toEmail, string subject, string emailBody)
{
    try
    {
        string senderEmail = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SenderEmail"].ToString();
        string senderPassword = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SenderPassword"].ToString();

        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
        {
            EnableSsl = true,
            Timeout = 100000,
            DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
            UseDefaultCredentials = false,
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential(senderEmail, senderPassword)
        };

        MailMessage message = new MailMessage(senderEmail, toEmail, subject, emailBody)
        {
            IsBodyHtml = true,
            BodyEncoding = UTF8Encoding.UTF8
        };

        client.Send(message); 

        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The view is as follows:

```js
var SendEmail = function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "Post",
        url: "/Home/SendMailToClients",
        success: function (data) {
            if (data == true) {
                alert("Message was sent successfully");
            }
            else
            {
                alert("Failure to send Message");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

```html
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>ASP.NET</h1>
        <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" onclick="SendEmail()">Send email now &raquo;</a></p>
</div>
```

The following error is what I get:

> 'System.Net.Mail.SmtpException' in System.dll

Comment: Please include details of any errors or exceptions?

Comment: Are you on a corporate network with Outlook running?  There is a proxy server blocking port 587.  Try code at home and see if it runs.

Comment: the url and the function name are different `SendMailToClients <> SendEmail`

Comment: show your data object , I mean what data you are going to post through ajax, as of now, You are showing your ajax code but not the data you are posting through ajax in "data" variable.

Comment: Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Mail.SmtpException' in System.dll That is the error I am getting. 

@jdweng I am on a corporate network with no outlook or mailexchange. I am trying to use gmail as my smtp.

Comment: @zulqadaridrishi I have updated the controller code to show the data I am trying to post through the ajax

Comment: @tawandaMasaiti `System.Net.Mail.SmtpException` is the exception type, not the error message you're getting. Replace `catch (Exception)` by `catch (Exception ex)` and show us `ex.Message`, `ex.InnerException.Message` if any, and stack trace.

Comment: You are use HTML which doesn't like a lot of characters.  You have to use System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode(string body);  See wiki : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references

Comment: found the problem. Gmail was blocking the email as an unsecure app to prevent spam. I created an app profile in gmail settings and got an auto generated password. this allowed the app to be recognised and allow the email to be processed by the smtp. Got a lead from @jdweng about proxy. Thanks for the assistance

Comment: If you are putting "type"=" post" then You have to put [HttpPost] attribute just before your JsonResult method. And then it will hit the method and the rest code will work